# There is something wrong in my code but i'm not sure what it is?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the sum of digits of the numbers that the user inputs,
what's wrong in my code? it appears to me that sum is underlined in the S.O.P..
but why is that? and how can I fix it?

```
package assignment7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment7_4_5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int number=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("sum: "+sumDigits (sum));
    }

    public static int sumDigits(int sum) {
        int number = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            sum = sum + number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: `number` should be in argument, `sum` should be local variable

Comment: Did you try compiling your code? What did you get?

Comment: This code won't even compile.  You should be passing the number you read as input into the helper function `sumDigits()`.  By the way, `sumDigits` looks spot-on to me.  Just fix `main()` and it should work.

Comment: Not sure about `sumDigits` - you initialise `number` to 0 and then run a loop while it is greater than 0. That loop won't run at all. EDIT: Yes, you have sum and number the wrong way around. You should be passing number, and initialising sum to 0 - this is what the first comment says

Comment: Maybe you need to revisit some Java basics. In your `main` method you define a local variable called `number`. This is the number you want to run `sumDigits` on. The method `sumDigits` demands one `int` argument. It will call this parameter `sum` inside of the method. So, to run `sumDigits` on `number`, you need to pass it into the method, as argument: `sumDigits(number)`. And inside the method, this argument is referred to by the name `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `sumDigits(sum)` to `sumDigits(number)` because number is the variable that you are passing to the method, the variable sum is not even declared before using the method sumDigits. Also in the function, the while loop will never execute because number is set to zero and the condition is `(number > 0)` which is never `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You have sum and number the wrong way around. You need to pass in number, as this is what you get from the user. Sum needs to be initialised to 0 in sumDigits, not number. Then you're incrementing sum and dividing down number, returning sum once you're finished. You also don't then skip over your while loop!

```
package assignment7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment7_4_5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int number=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("sum: "+sumDigits (number));
    }

    public static int sumDigits(int number) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            sum = sum + number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```